# Usage of DataRow.BeginEdit() and DataRow.EndEdit() for single change

Tags: c#, dataset

I have quite a lot of code in the following form:

```
// assume that MyDataRow is a datarow from a typed dataset and has a property called SomeInt 
MyDataRow row;

row.BeginEdit();
row.SomeInt = 42;
row.EndEdit();
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datarow.beginedit(v=vs.110).aspx) of DataRow.BeginEdit states the following:

> Use the BeginEdit method to put a DataRow into edit mode. In this
>   mode, events are temporarily suspended, letting the user make changes
>   to more than one row without triggering validation rules.

So, in the given case, when there is only one change, the usage of the BeginEdit- and EndEdit-methods is not needed at all, or am I missing something? I.e. is it safe to just get rid of these calls, or is it good practice to keep them?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working by `binding data to control`, then use `BeginEdit() and EndEdit()` **always**. There may be `events or triggers` on your project, and if you will not use `BeginEdit() and EndEdit()` your `assigned value` may change in any `event or trigger`, and it will take a lot of time to find bug.

Comment: That's a good point! However, there are and won't be any events or triggers on these datarows... so it it safe to assume that this won't be an issue.